# Install app on tiny core

Tags: mysql, tinycore

How do you install `mysql` on tiny core? Also how do you install `clamav`? Can you install `apt-get` or `yum` on tiny core?

All should be done in command line / terminal

Answer (score 1):

MySQL isnt avaialble for Tiny Core, but mariadb v10.0.19 is. Mariadb is a drop-in replacement for MySQL.

ClamAV isn't in the TC repository, so isn't currently available.

The Apt-get and YUM package managers are for entirely different distributions and therefore not usable with TC.

The TC command line app browser (tce-ab) can install mariadb in on-demand mode, or mount mode.

Answer (score 0):

I know the broad answer is to use the app browser:
http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/download_howto.html
That is to say that is how you install applications from a broad perspective. Having said that, I am not sure it addresses your specific question.

Comment: They app browser helps. But I am not sure if it has mysql

Comment: I am currently deciding the best OS for my server